# UIScrollview with one large view, or UITableview with multible views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm working on a project that has a detailed view of a company's information. On the lower half of the view I have some buttons that don't move, but above them I have more content, that I can not fit into the screen for a 4s. So I'm thinking I should create a new view and insert that view or views into a TableView, or a ScrollView.

What I'm not sure about is if I should create sectional views for each part of the page, e.g. hero image that the header of the page, company titles and description, other photos, etc, then take each view and add them to a Tableview, or should I create one big view with all them elements and insert it into a ScrollView. Which is the standard/best choice for displaying content in a app thats beyond the height of the area?

I provided an example of my detailed view. I want everything above the Message/Call buttons to scroll up/down so I can fit more content.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this really easily with a static UITableView.

Take a look at my blog. It explains in detail how to do this.

You don't even need a datasource or anything.

http://www.oliverfoggin.com/using-a-static-uitableview-as-a-layout-device/

Comment: As a side note. Take a look at my latest blog. You can now (for iOS 9) use UIStackView. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use a UITableView, and make each individual cell in nib file (*.xib) and programatically register the cells.

That way you can reorder the segments, and easily edit the cells in isolation, controlling the position and heights of each cell in the view controller.

If your view controller that contains these details is a subclass of UITableViewController then I would recommend what @Fogmeister suggests and use a static UITableView, because it is easier to add actions to your "Message" and "Call" buttons without breaking the Model-View-Controller pattern, but you can only use a static UITableView in UITableViewController subclasses.